# How can I implement SlickGrid DatePicker in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, slickgrid

This following code disables some dates and highlights some others in the jQuery DatePicker UI.

```
var disabledDays = ["2013-12-14", "2014-1-21", "2014-1-24", "2011-7-27", "2014-1-28"];
var date = new Date();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dp").datepicker({
        buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'both',
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var m = date.getMonth(),
                d = date.getDate(),
                y = date.getFullYear();
            for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d, disabledDays) != -1) {
                    return [true, 'ui-state-active', ''];
                }
            }
            return [false];
        }
    });
});
```

How can I implement the same code in a JavaScript?

SlickGrid DatePicker found here :
[slickgrid datepicker example](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example4-model.html)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for exactly. If you are asking how to implement SlickGrid DatePicker without jQuery but in pure JavaScript then no, that is not possible. It does state in the wiki documentation under [**dependencies**](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki#dependencies) that jQuery is required. If you are asking how to replicate the same functionality without jQuery and SlickGrid then you have to go through the source files rip that code out and re-write it yourself in oure JavaScript. If that is not what you were asking please clarify your question.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to not use jQuery, when you implement the datepicker in slickgrid you don't have the possibility to work on dates by highlighting some of them as shown in my code , I can't find the selector $(".dp") in my datepicker in the grid.